# How to iterate through 2 DataSources in SoapUI Pro

Tags: xml, groovy, automation, soapui

**Goal:** Iterate through 2 DataSources to update the properties in the "Assert Properties are Equal" Groovy script.

**Problem:** Test case is only iterating through the rows in the "GetAppointmentInfo-> Properties" DataSource.  The properties from the "Stratus_ODS-> Properties" DataSource are stuck on the first row of the datasource and not updated as the test case loops.

Image of test Case here (sorry, needed 10 rep to put image inline):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qaXn.jpg

**Test Case Steps and description:**

1. REST Request "Start Get Key" - responds with security key required for 2nd request
2. Property Transfer "Key -> GetAppointmentInfo" - transfers security key to GetAppointmentInfo Request
3. REST Request "GetAppointmentInfo" - responds with list of appointments in XML
4. DataSource "GetAppointmentInfo -> Properties" - Source "GetAppointmentInfo" response, stores a column of Appointment Numbers as a property named "ApptNum".  The appointment numbers are [100,101,102,103,104]
5. DataSource "Stratus_ODS -> Properties" - Source is table in SQL Server Database, stores a column of Appointment Numbers as a property named "SQL_ApptNum".  The appointment numbers are [100,101,102,103,104]
6. Groovy Script Step "Assert Properties are Equal"

   ```
   def ApptNum = context.expand( '${GetAppointmentInfo->Properties#ApptNum}' )
   def SQL_ApptNum = context.expand( '${Stratus_ODS->Properties#SQL_ApptNum}' )
   assert ApptNum == SQL_AptNum
   ```
7. DataSource Loop - Source: Step 4 "GetAppointmentInfo -> Properties" & Target:  Step 6 "Assert Properties are Equal"

**Assertion passes on first iteration when:**

ApptNum =100  &  SQL_ApptNum = 100

**Assertion fails on second iteration when:**

ApptNum =101  &  SQL_ApptNum = 100

Comment: I don't have a SOAPUI PRO version and I can't use `Data Source` test steps, however did you check if `Restart On Run` property is set in `Data Source` options in your `Stratus_ODS -> Properties` test step? seems that it's set because each iteration is using the first result because it's probably executing the query each time, I think that if you need the described behavior this property must be unset.

Comment: You have **two** DataSource steps, and only **one** DataSource Loop step?

Comment: @albciff I have "Restart datasource when step is run" unchecked on both DataSources.

Comment: @SiKing Yes I do.  I've tried adding a second data source loop but am still having the same result.  If, adding a second DataSource Loop would resolve the issue would you be able to tell me which step # to make it and what the Source and Target of it should be?

Comment: I cannot understand how do steps 1,2,3 relate to steps 4,5,6. They seem to have absolutely nothing in common. There is no information flowing between these two groups of steps! I think your entire test design is flawed.

Comment: @SiKing Steps 1-3 are required to get the XML response with a list of appointments.  Should this be in a separate test case?

Comment: OK, I think I get it. Step 4 extracts the information out of step 3?

Comment: @SiKing Yes, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your test design is flawed. You still have some information missing, so the following is only my best guess!

Approach it something like this:

1. "Start Get Key"
2. You could probably combine "Key -> GetAppointmentInfo" and "GetAppointmentInfo" into one step, but I would have to see the details of what is going on there. For now leave them as they are.
3. "GetAppointmentInfo -> Properties"
4. "Stratus_ODS -> Properties" **this is the source of your problems**! Change this to a JDBC step, and you will have to craft a SQL statement to extract the values one at a time from your database. Again, I do not know the details of your app; talk to your db developer.
5. "Assert Properties are Equal" You could probably merge this into step 4 as a Script Assertion, but leave it if you are more comfortable with this.
6. "GetAppointmentInfo -> Properties" back to your DataSource (step 3 above), target the step immediately following.

Comment: I added the ApptNum property from my step 4 "GetAppointmentInfo -> Properties" to the WHERE clause in the SQL query in my step 5 "Stratus_ODS -> Properties" DataSource DataConnection (did not need to change to JDBC for this).  Then I added and directed the DataSource loop as you described in your step 6.  Thank you very much!